# GWT ImageResource method names not known beforehand

Tags: gwt

I am building a website using GWT. I have made a "filmstrip" which will scroll images on click of a button. Now, in GWT, there is a ClientBundle interface which allows for small images to be grouped together so that all can be downloaded as a single large image in http requests. This cuts down on the request/response overhead. For this there is an ImageResource interface. Now, this interface requires that the method name which loads the image should be known and declared beforehand and that it should be identical to the image file name excluding the file extension. The admin for the website would load random photographs and any number of them, hence, I would neither know the number of methods to declare nor their names beforehand. Any suggestions regarding enabling this? -Thanks!

Comment: As @Riley says, it's a compile-time thing. Unless you have some other tool to "concatenate images" and express the original as a subrectangle of the merged one... you can't do nothing special. I'd focus on retrieving the image through some URL/servlet and that's it... or using `data:` format removing the need for a separate request for each image (given the image data is expressed as a string).

Comment: Using [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as @helios suggests has its pitfalls, e.g. IE9's 32KiB content limitation.

Comment: I've read that the 32KB limits is IE8's, but anyway it's a pitfall. I should go for simple file-per-request retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

ClientBundle and ImageResource are compile-time optimizations.  You cannot add more images at run time.